# CakePHP Nested Url not working

Tags: url, cakephp, nested

Is it possible to have more than one folder inside the View/Pages? 
I want the following url structure
domain.com/pages/folder1/folder2/page1.ctp

I created the page, and the link. But when I hit the link the url gets corrupted like:
domain.com/pages/folder1%2Ffolder2%2Fpage1  and it shows a "not found error".
When I replace the characters with the correct symbol (/) the page shows fine.

So it basically transforms the " / " to the html equal of " %2F "
It does this in my test localhost web server (Wamp) and in the production server (public domain).

I created the link with the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Underwater Museum', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'excursions/grenada-island/underwater-museum')); ?>
```

Y have my charset set to UTF-8 both in my core: Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
and in my database.php to:  'encoding' => 'utf8'

Any help It would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: What is the exact link you want? What was the actual link that was generated? What is the cakephp code that that generated the link?

Answer (score 0):

You dont basically hit URL with the path of the actual view pages, what you do is you call the controller method that has the corresponding view with the a standard URL that cake defines, now if u want to give different folders other than the ones cakephp uses by default, you can take a look at this:

http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Change-view-folder-inside-a-Controller-td5711244.html

That being said, if that is not what u want, and are actually looking to change URL patterns with whatever method u hit, you should take a look at cakephp routing for that.

In ur URL its treating ur this part 'excursions/grenada-island/underwater-museum' as a string, whereas here the method should be passed and called which in turn calls the subsequent view with the nested folder structure that you want. Hope this helps.